# Moving square on a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

here's my code for moving a square on a canvas. Basicly I'm creating this thinking of some simple simulations or maybe a simple game. Would love some feedback how to optimize the code.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class Map {
    constructor (x, y,) {
        this.width = x;
        this.height = y;
    }
}

// NPCs / PLAYER

class Square {
    constructor(hp, dmg, speed, step) {
        // Combat stats
        this.hp = hp;
        this.dmg = dmg;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.step = step;
        
        // Init stats
        this.size = 10;
        this.color = 'black';
        this.pos = [0,0];
        this.step = 2;
    }
}

class Player extends Square {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.speed = 50; // The higher the slower the player
        this.pos = [250, 250];
        this.step = 5;
    }
}

let player;

function drawPlayer() {
    ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
    ctx.fillRect(player.pos[0], player.pos[1], player.size, player.size);
}

function createSquare() {
    const square = new Square(100, 15, 20);
    ctx.fillStyle = square.color;
    ctx.fillRect(square.pos[0], square.pos[1], square.size, square.size);
}

function initPlayer() {
    player = new Player(100, 15, 1, 5);
    ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
    ctx.fillRect(player.pos[0], player.pos[1], player.size, player.size);
}


// MOVEMENT

function startMov() {
    initPlayer();
    movePlayer();
}

function moveUp(step) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, 500, 500);
    player.pos[1] -= step;
    drawPlayer();
}

function moveLeft(step) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, 500, 500);
    player.pos[0] -= step;
    drawPlayer();
}

function moveDown(step) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, 500, 500);
    player.pos[1] += step;
    drawPlayer();
}

function moveRight(step) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, 500, 500);
    player.pos[0] += step;
    drawPlayer();
}


let keyState = new Array();

function movePlayer() {
    console.log('start')
    checkIfStringInTable('a', keyState) ? moveLeft(player.step) : false;
    checkIfStringInTable('d', keyState) ? moveRight(player.step) : false;
    checkIfStringInTable('w', keyState) ? moveUp(player.step) : false;
    checkIfStringInTable('s', keyState) ? moveDown(player.step) : false;
    setTimeout(movePlayer,player.speed);
}

// Add keys to state
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    addKeyToState(e.key);
})

// Remove keys from state
window.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    removeKeyFromState(e.key);
})

function addKeyToState(key) {
    if((key == 'w' || key == 'a' || key == 's' || key == 'd') && !checkIfStringInTable(key,keyState)) {
        keyState.push(key)
    } else false;
}

function removeKeyFromState(key) {
    keyState = keyState.filter(e => e !== key)
}

function checkIfStringInTable(string, table) {
    if(table.indexOf(string) > -1) {
        return true;
    } else false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="createSquare()">Click</button>
    <button onclick="startMov()">Click 2</button>
    <div class="main">
        <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    </div>
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

To start press Click 2, I also suggest using SO's fullscreen mode for testing.